# Nativescript how to save image to file in custom component

Tags: nativescript

I have created a custom component that access the device's camera to snap a picture, set it as source of an `ImageView` and then save it to a file.
Here is the Javascript code

> CAMERA.JS

Here is the initialization of the imageView

```
export function cameraLoaded(args):void{
    cameraPage = <Page> args.object;
    imageView = <Image> cameraPage.getViewById("img_upload");...
}
```

Here I set the `imageViews`'source to the just taken picture

```
export function takePicture():void{
    camera.takePicture(
        {
        })
        .then(
            function(picture){
                imageView.imageSource = picture;
        },function(error){
    });
}
```

This works perfectly.

Now I try to save the picture to a file.

```
export function saveToFile():void{

    try {
        let saved = imageView.imageSource.saveToFile(path,enums.ImageFormat.png);
        HalooseLogger.log(saved,"upload");
        })
    }catch (e){
      ...
    }
}
```

Here I get an error `cannot read property saveToFile of undefined`
This is very unusual, in fact if I `console.log(imageView)` here is the output :

```
Image<img_upload>@file:///app/views/camera/camera.xml:4:5;
```

but if I `console.log(imageView.imageSource`) i see it is ´undefined`.
**How is this possible? What am I doing wrong?**

**ADDITIONAL INFO**
The previous code and relatex xml is included in another view as follows :

> MAIN.XML

```
<Page 
 xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
 xmlns:cameraPage="views/camera" 
 loaded="loaded">
<StackLayout orientation="vertical">
    <StackLayout id="mainContainer">
    <!-- DYNAMIC CONTENT GOES HERE -->
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
</Page>
```

> MAIN.JS

This is were the camera view gets loaded dynamically

```
export function loaded(args):void{
    mainPage = <Page>args.object;
    contentWrapper = mainPage.getViewById("mainContainer");
 DynamicLoaderService.loadPage(mainPage,contentWrapper,mainViewModel.currentActive);
}
```

The `loadPage` method does the following :

```
 public static loadPage(pageElement,parentElement,currentActive):void{
        let component = Builder.load({
            path : "views/camera",
            name : "camera",
            page : pageElement
        });
        parentElement.addChild(component);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that as of NativeScript 2.4.0 the **Image** created for Android will always return null for its property ***imageSource***. Currently, optimisations are on the way to prevent Out of Memory related issues when working with multiple large images and that is why **image-asset** was presented in nativeScript 2.4.0.

Now I am not sure if you are using the latest **[nativescript-camera](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-camera)** (highly recommended) but if so you should consider that the promise from takePicture() is returning imageAsset. Due to the memory optimization imageSource will always return **undefined** (for Android) unless you specifically create one. You can do that with fromAsset() method providing the ImageAsset returned from the camera callback.

Example:

```
import { EventData } from 'data/observable';
import { Page } from 'ui/page';

import { Image } from "ui/image";
import { ImageSource, fromAsset } from "image-source";
import { ImageAsset } from "image-asset";

import * as camera from "nativescript-camera";
import * as fs from "file-system";

var imageModule = require("ui/image");
var img;
var myImageSource: ImageSource;

// Event handler for Page "navigatingTo" event attached in main-page.xml
export function onLoaded(args: EventData) {
    // Get the event sender
    let page = <Page>args.object;

    img = <Image>page.getViewById("img");

    camera.requestPermissions();
}

export function takePhoto() {
    camera.takePicture()
        .then(imageAsset => {
            console.log("Result is an image asset instance");
            img.src = imageAsset;

            fromAsset(imageAsset).then(res => {
                myImageSource = res;
                console.log(myImageSource);
            })
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Error -> " + err.message);
        });
}

export function saveToFile(): void {



    var knownPath = fs.knownFolders.documents();
    var folderPath = fs.path.join(knownPath.path, "CosmosDataBank");

    var folder = fs.Folder.fromPath(folderPath);
    var path = fs.path.join(folderPath, "Test.png");

    var saved = myImageSource.saveToFile(path, "png");
    console.log(saved);
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Where can I learn about these new plugins and way of doing things?